# angularjs set default date input at today

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date

I try to set the **default value of an input field at today**. I can do that with an **text field** but when I try with an **date field** it **fails**.

HTML code :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="new">
        <input type="date" ng-model="date_rdv" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="form_text" />
    </form>
</div>
```

JS code :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.form_text = $filter('date')(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    $scope.date_Rdv = $filter('date')(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

Why it works with text field and not with date field ?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68j7y439/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not referencing the correct property of $scope.

Either use:

`$scope.date_rdv = $filter('date')(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');`

Or

`<input type="date" ng-model="date_rdv" />`.

I've updated your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/68j7y439/1/

Comment: No problem, always good to have an extra pair of eyes some times!